# Unexpected red rectangle on the UI in the review queue (suggested edits)

Tags: support, bug, review

This is the first time I happen to see this, so it seems to be unexpected to me. This appeared in the "Suggested Edits" review queue for me a couple of minutes ago after this reviewing [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3599117).

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]